# Delphi IDE: how to save toolbar layout and restore after reinstall?

Tags: delphi, layout, ide

A very annoying thing when reinstalling Delphi, is having to set again my layout exactly as I had it. There are options to save/restore within the current install, but nothing to import it from a previous version/install, where are these settings stored?

[image]

Comment: Try to backup reg. key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<BorGearDero>\BDS\<IDEVersion>\Toolbars` and restore it after reinstalling (described [`here`](http://delphi.longzu.net/viewthread.php?tid=49256)). I don't think there's a built-in option for this.

Comment: Everything is stored in registry, look for Embarcadero keys under HKCU and HKLM.

Comment: Does CnWizards export those settings along with others ?

Comment: @Arioch, I would say yes. The option "IDE Configuration in Registry" in the IDE Config Backup/Restore Tool includes also toolbar settings as far as I remember.

Comment: Thanks, TLama's tip worked, can you post it as Answer so I will accept and close. Thank you.